# How to lock down the Bazel filesystem sandbox?

Tags: bazel

The default Bazel sandbox allows read access to `/`. How can I further restrict that? E.g. I would like to prevent non-hermetic tests from accessing the `/search` directory.

There was a `--sandbox_block_path` flag but it [was removed](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/3e2329a73ffd5d60e5e2babe60ebe5bf322c07da) in 0.5.

Comment: A simple approach would be to execute Bazel as a specific user and disabling read access to `/search` with ACL.

Comment: "The default Bazel sandbox allows read access to `/`." -- That sounds like a bug. Could you please file it at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new, and add any information that could be relevant please? (E.g. Which Bazel version or commit hash did you see this bug at, what flags you passed on the command line, anything that could be relevant.) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reporting that the removal of this feature is a problem for you. I found a way how to make it work reliably on Linux and macOS and will bring it back. Code review is already sent to a colleague. I'll make sure it gets cherry-picked into Bazel 0.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this back. Is there a good explanation of why `/` is readable by default? My conception of a sandbox designed to enforce hermeticity is to lock down everything by default and force users to specify a very limited, say, `--sandbox_allow_path` list rather than the reverse. How does Google do it?

Comment: @Gregg "lock down everything by default, except a whitelist" was Bazel's first attempt at sandboxing and very unpopular with users due to the amount of work involved. That said, the sandbox is still evolving and we might add a stricter version (as an opt-in) of it again in the future. :) By the way, the --sandbox_allow_path change didn't make it into the 0.5.0/0.5.1 release, but will be included in the 0.5.2 release, including another new flag that might be helpful for you (--sandbox_writable_path).

Comment: @PhilippWollermann can you maybe add link to the github issue or commit?